# The name "'_emailSender'" does not exist in the current context

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm trying to learn authentication on razor pages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

And when I changed the Login page as they wrote in the example-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
                                          .ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", 
                                      new { email = Input.Email });
            }
            else
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

I get the error-
The name "'_emailSender'" does not exist in the current context

And I searched later if there is a reference to the _emailSender class and did not see. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I should have added -

```
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
```

Too bad they did not write it, it would have saved me a lot of time